# Filtering out non null values from a collection in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, null, nullable, kotlin-null-safety

Take a look at this kotlin one liner:

```
val nonNullArr : List<NonNullType> = nullArray.filter {it != null}
```

The compiler gives a type error at this line, saying that a list of nullables can't be assigned to a list of non-nulls. But the filter conditional makes sure that the list will only contain non null values. Is there something similar to `!!` operator that I can use in this situation to  make this code compile?

Comment: Use `nullArray.filterNotNull()` instead.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It seems logical to assume that the compiler would take into account the predicate

```
it != null
```

and infer the type as

```
List<NonNullType>
```

but it does not. 
There are 2 solutions:

```
val nonNullList: List<NonNullType>  = nullableArray.filterNotNull()
```

or

```
val nonNullList: List<NonNullType>  = nullableArray.mapNotNull { it }
```

Comment: what if List has no-null objects but i want to filter based on some key of that object whose value is null. How about doing that ?

Comment: @zero first map the list to the key, then filter not null and filter original list according to result equality.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you cannot convert nullable types into nonNull types by just verifying that they are not null. To achieve what you want, you need to manually map nullable values to non-null type by simply creating NonNull type object. For this you can use map extension function.

```
val nullableArray: Array<String?> = arrayOf("abc", "xyz", null, "efg")

val nonNullList: List<String> = nullableArray.filter { it != null }.map {
    it.toString()
}
```

Or you can use `filterNotNull()` method as @forpas suggested in comments

```
val nonNullList: List<String>  = nullableArray.filterNotNull()
```

Hope it helps you!

Answer (score 1):

You can't assign a nullable type to a non-nullable type of value. 
The type-matching maybe works when you assign a value, not after `filter` operation called.

```
// the type-matching works before `.filter` is called
val nonNullArr : List<NonNullType> = nullArray//.filter {it != null}
```

instead, if you want to do this without an error or without concerning the type. Remove the type from the `val`, so it goes like this

```
val nonNullArr = nullArray.filter {it != null}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score -2):

try using **listOfNotNull** instead of listOf(), it is equivalent to **list.filterNotNull()**